# No me coge la ruta de archivos que es PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

php, en este cuando el usuario se logea aparecerá su nombre de usuario arriba en el header, cuando paso el mouse por el nombre del usuario, se despliegue una opción que se llama cerrar sesión, mi problema es que lo tengo configurado para cuando le de clic en cerrar sesión vaya a cerrarsesion.php y me corra esto. Se supone que por la linea header('Location: ../index.php'); debería ir a index.php pero no lo hace

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location: ../index.php');
?>
```

Todo mi proyecto esta dentro una carpeta que se llama Ecommerce, dentro de esta, está el index.php que es donde estoy en el momento de darle clic a salir, mi archivo cerrarsesion.php esta dentro de una carpeta dentro de Ecommerce que se llama servicios y allí esta mi archivo, no entiendo porque cuando le doy clic a cerrar sesion me lleva a http://localhost/Ecommerce/cerrarsesion.php en vez de redireccionarme a index.php pero obviamente ya con la sesion cerrada.

PD: Si pongo cerrarsesion.php a la misma altura que index.php si funciona.

Comment: Puedes agregar tu codigo donde estas llamando a cerrarsesion.php, es decir, adjunta el codigo donde le das clic al hipervinculo que te cierra la sesión. De acuerdo a como comentas, debería cogerte bien la ruta

Comment: ´<a href="cerrarsesion.php">Cerrar Sesion</a>´

Comment: En lugar de usar ruta relativa en el location, prueba con ruta absoluta desde la raiz del dominio hasta la carpeta donde este el index.php

Comment: @masterguru dices así? header('Location: /Ecommerce/index.php');

Comment: Sí, si tu index esta en esa carpeta dejalo así, debería funcionar... y si no te funciona es por que o no pasa por alli o porque aunque pase luego hace algo más y deberias matarlo despues del location con un die() o exit() para que no continue con el resto de código

Comment: Creo que no te habia entendido bien lo que decias antes... a ver.. si tu enlace es este: `<a href="cerrarsesion.php">Cerrar Sesion</a>` y en tu url actual **no** estas en la carpeta /Ecommerce/servicios/loquesea.php, entonces no te va a funcionar. Para que te funcione tambien debes poner la ruta absoluta en el enlace así: `<a href="/Ecommerce/servicios/cerrarsesion.php">Cerrar Sesion</a>` porque sino no va a encontrar cerrarsession.php y lo va a buscar en la carpeta actual donde este tu url actual

Comment: Son dos errores los que creo que tenias, uno en el enlace que acabo de comentar, y el otro en el location... debes corregir ambos para asegurarte de que te va a funcionar bien en todos los casos sea cual sea y este en la ruta que sea el script que llama a cerrarsession.php (que a su vez encontrará a index.php en el location con la ruta absoluta tal como he dicho antes)

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, me equivoque cuando te corregí en el anterior comentario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu archivo index es así:

```
<html>
<body>
<header>
<a href="cerrarsesion.php"> Cerrar sesion</a>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Y la ruta de index.php es Ecommerce/index.php, realmente ahí en el hipervínculo requieres indicarle en que carpeta está tu archivo cerrarsesion.php

Ya que así como está tu codigo: `<a href="cerrarsesion.php"> Cerrar sesion</a>` asumes que cerrarsesion.php está en el mismo lugar que index.php y debería mandarte un warning con esta ruta: http://localhost/Ecommerce/cerrarsesion.php

Reemplázalo de esta forma:

```
<a href="servicios/cerrarsesion.php"> Cerrar sesion</a>
```

Y tu archivo cerrarsesion.php queda igual, bueno, solo te hice una sugerencia de que retires el sesion_start ya que no tiene utilidad debido a que vas a destruir variables de sesión, no a iniciarlas

```
<?php
#Archivo cerrarsesion.php
session_start(); 
session_destroy(); 
header('Location: ../index.php');
?>
```

Comment: Todo muy bien pero la parte de borrar session_start(); al quitarla no me cierra sesion, sabes por que es?

Comment: Que raro, entonces... dejando el session_start(); seguido del session_destroy(); si te cierra la sesión?

Comment: Así es, cuando pongo los 2 si se me cierra.

Comment: Es correcto el uso de ambas, ya edité la respuesta para no crear confusiones. aunque en mi caso, funciona simplemente si utilizo session_destroy();